# Can't assign List Iterator [C++]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I have the following method:

```
void* vpArr_t::operator[](int i) const
{
    if (!isEmpty() && i >= 0 && i < nOfItems)
    {
        list<void*>::iterator it;
        int idx;
        for(it = array.begin(), idx = 0; idx < i; ++it, ++idx); // go to the i'th element 
        return *it;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Where:

`array` is a list type.

I'm getting a red underline (compilation error) in the following line:

```
for(it = array.begin(), idx = 0; idx < i; ++it, ++idx);
```

at:

```
it = array.begin()
```

it says that I'm tring to set a `list<void*>::const_iterator` into a `list<void*>::iterator` type.

But I noticed that there's a `iterator` overloading for the `begin()` method. how to solve this error? I'm using Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: can you try auto instead of list<void*>::iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `array` is a data member, and you are in a `const` member function, so you cannot call non-const methods on data members. So you need a `const_iterator`:

```
list<void*>::const_iterator it,
```

Comment: @user1798362 You should be able to increment it fine. Are you sure you didn't do `const list<void*>::const_iterator` or something?

Comment: Now I do, but for so reason, it doesn't increment the iterator, and it stucks on 0x0000000, even though the loops runs 2 times

Comment: @user1798362 there could be many other problems. But if the loop runs two times, it is impossible that the iterator is not incremented, because the loop relies on the iterator incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `array` is a member of `vpArr_t`. Since this `vpArr_t::operator[]` overload is declared `const`, the members of `vpArr_t` are effectively also `const`. This ensures that you do not modify the `vpArr_t` object's state. Since `array` is effectively `const`, when you call `begin` on it, you get a `const_iterator`.

Since you aren't actually modifying the contents of `array`, you should change your iterator type to `const_iterator`:

```
list<void*>::const_iterator it;
```

If you do actually want to use a non-`const` iterator because you want to modify the contents of `array`, you'll need to make `operator[]` a non-`const` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `list<void*>::const_iterator it` instead: `array` is probably a const reference or a member variable in the class not marked as `mutable`. Your function is marked as const so member data cannot be modified within it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you can't use `iterator` but have to use `const_iterator`, there is a function that can help you:

```
list<void*>::const_iterator it = arary.begin();
std::advance(it, i);
```

That said, calling a doubly-linked list an array is questionable. Also, this isn't really efficient, using a `vector<>` or `deque<>` would give you constant-time access to the i-th element. Also, I would use `size_t` for the index, which is more consistent with the rest of the C++ standardlibrary.